# replicate javascript generated table on other divs with different amount of rows and cells

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a code that helps me to generate a table of 0's and 1's within a div that serves as container. It works for now, but not sure how to proceed to introduce same code but different amount of cells and rows for each table on different divs across the website (randomNumbers2, randomNumbers3, randomNumbers4, randomNumbers5, etc)

So basically I want to use same code to generate another table with 0's and 1's on the other div randomNumbers3 but instead of 8 rows and 8 cells, to make it 16. Or even to include a certain amount (at same distance) based on the width and height of the div container. to keep it proportional across all the divs that generate tables.

```js
var totalRows = 8;
var cellsInRow = 8;
var min = 0;
var max = 1;


    function drawTable() {
        // get the reference for the body
        var randomNumbers2 = document.querySelector('.randomNumbers2');
 
        // creates a <table> element
        var tbl = document.createElement("table");
        tbl.style.width = '100%';
        tbl.style.height = '100%';
 
        // creating rows
        for (var r = 0; r < totalRows; r++) {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
         
         // create cells in row
             for (var c = 0; c < cellsInRow; c++) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
        getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }           
            
    tbl.appendChild(row);
        }
    
     randomNumbers2.appendChild(tbl);
}
window.onload=drawTable;
```

```css
.randomNumbers2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
 }
 
 .randomNumbers3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="randomNumbers2"></div>
<div class="randomNumbers3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `drawTable()` function to be a helper function and pass parameters to create your table

```
var min = 0;
var max = 1;

function drawTable(divElement, totalRows, cellsInRow) {
    // get the reference for the body
    var randomNumbers = document.querySelector(divElement);

    // creates a <table> element
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    tbl.style.width = '100%';
    tbl.style.height = '100%';

    // creating rows
    for (var r = 0; r < totalRows; r++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        // create cells in row
        for (var c = 0; c < cellsInRow; c++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            var cellText = document.createTextNode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        tbl.appendChild(row);
    }

    randomNumbers.appendChild(tbl);
}
window.onload = (event) => {
    drawTable(".randomNumbers2", 8, 8);
    drawTable(".randomNumbers3", 16, 16);
};
```

Comment: thanks for that @SG07 but one thing, the rows on the second one (randomNumbers3) is going beyond the div limits, is there a way to limit the height of each row to fit between the numbers defined on the totalRows Var? maybe I have to insert  a row.style.height = tbl.height / totalRows? and insert it below the var row?

Comment: You can't otherwise you reduce the text font size also. The row size can not be smaller than the font size. Why don't you opt to adjust the size of the table to fit the size of rows with the minimum row size without affecting the font size instead. Use ```tbl.style.height = 'inherit';``` instead of ```tbl.style.height = '100%';``` and change your css also ```.randomNumbers3 {height: inherit;}```